# Can I still use regular redux actions with redux-thunk middleware applied?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'd like to use `redux-thunk` for a project I'm working on, but I don't want to rewrite my action creation functions for obvious reasons.

Is `redux-thunk` smart enough to recognize that I'm not using a thunk in my dispatch? This would allow me to write new async actions without rewriting my existing actions to return a thunk.

Comment: Yes, `redux-thunk` only adds the ability to use `async` actions

Comment: Thunks are only a middleware, so yes, Redux still works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the thunk middleware just passes through anything that is not a function (ie, plain action objects).

Note that you *should* be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) to write your logic.  RTK's `configureStore` automatically sets up the thunk middleware for you, and RTK's `createSlice` automatically generates all those action creators based on the reducers you provide.  You shouldn't ever have to write an action creator by hand, ever again.

Please see [Redux Fundamentals, Part 8: Modern Redux with Redux Toolkit](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) for examples of how RTK simplifies hand-written redux logic.